# O365 API error when filtering on EventType

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

I am querying the /Me/Events endpoint with the filter parameter of

```
$filter=Type eq Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EventType'SeriesMaster'
```

to return only recurring events. However, this query returns the following error messages:

```
The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'Microsoft.Exchange.Entities.DataModel.Calendaring.EventType' and 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EventType'
```

I have not been able to find documentation on *Microsoft.Exchange.Entities.DataModel.Calendaring.EventType*.

I am bewildered as to why it thinks "Type" property is of that type when the namespace schema shows it is of type *Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EventType*.

Has anyone else come across this? What is the best way to filter on this property or to only return recurring event masters?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and we are working to fix it ASAP. Thanks for reporting it. I will get back to you once the fix is rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem building my app. 
Hope to have that bug fix ASAP.

**Some notes regarding this issue:**
I believe we should be able to see and get the recurrent events on the day they were schedule even if this recurrence was added in the past. I have events that were added months ago and I am fetching data for the current day. I think it doesn't make much sense the need to fetch the all events with SeriesMaster type and then identify those that actually are schedule for the current day.

Comment: Thanks bzin, 
Yes, we are working on getting to filter on Type.
BTW, the recurrence events for a given time period can be queried using the below query.The Type will be 'Occurence'

../EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=End%20ge%202014-06-06T22:30:00Z%20and%20Start%20le%202020-12-14T22:30:00Z

All times are in UTC

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I do not get recurrence events when they were added in the past. 

When I do the query:
`/Events?$filter=Start ge 2014-07-10T22:00:00Z and End le 2014-07-11T22:00:00Z `

The dates I use to start and end are just the day length. The recurrence events added in the past do not show in this output.

Comment: Hi Bzin, you have to use the ordering of "end ge <x> and start le <y>, rather than "start ge and end le", I know it is not intuitive and we will fix it soon, but in the meantime, try the one i have suggested and it should work.